# Spark Find a particular string between all lines of a csv file python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark and i have a large csv file.
The csv file is  having multiple lines

```
<ABCosmswkmwPQR>
<ABCasdfasdfadsPQR>
 ...
 ...
```

I need to iterate through each line and find the text between the particular string in it. I am using regex to do it

```
text_file = sc.textFile("file:///path/subset.tsv")
s = text_file.first()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyFirstStandaloneApp')
links = re.findall(r'ABC(.*?)\PQR', s)


sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

But I am only able to do this for only the first line. How do i do it for all files of the line. I need to iterate line by line and write the output of matched regex to a list if it fits into memory or a file.

I have opened the file using sparkcontext and I have to do the same since I have to read the file from HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
read_lines = open("file.csv", "r")
for line in read_lines:
    #if line matches regex:
        #do something
```

`read_lines` reads the entire file and the for loop will loop each line in the file. You just have to plug in the regex code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_extract` from module `pyspark.sql.functions`.
IF your file is `temp.csv`

```
spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("temp.csv"), schema=StringType()).
                        select(regexp_extract(regexpattern, col, idx)
```